# how to configure the WSO2BPS to subscribe to the event stream from a WSO2CEP

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process, wso2-cep

my design of the system is to use the CEP as the "engine" of the system, so that customer requests will be sent over to the CEP as events, and then will be re-routed to the BPS to trigger different business processes.

my question is : 
How may I configure the BPS to subscribe to a event stream(or streams) from CEP, and  'trigger' the execution of a business process?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 CEP is capable of communicating with several protocols such as http, jms, mqtt, thrift, tcp and soap. For your case you can use soap protocol.

On the WSO2 BPS side you can create a BPEL workflow. You can use WSO2 developer studio to create a project. When creating BPEL process you could use XPath expressions and access RequestMessage attributes (Which will be the CEP stream attributes). Once you create BPEL process you can export it and upload it wo WSO2 BPEL which will be exposed as a service. Please refer [Creating a BPEL Workflow Tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/Creating+a+BPEL+Workflow)

In CEP side you have the stream and have to create a soap publisher for that stream and you can point to WSO2 BPEL service.

Comment: Hello, Tharik, thanks very much for the quick repsonse, do you have a detailed description on "use XPath expressions and access RequestMessage attributes"

Comment: It should be something like this 
not($input.payload/tns:divisor=0)

Please refer following tutorial
http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/04/using-carbon-studio-model-wsbpel-process-using-bpel-editor/